# EOS Node Build Help

Tags: nodeos, eosio-code, node, build

I'm new to development so hopefully someone can point out what I may have done wrong.

I'm trying to set up an EOS node using Ubuntu VirtualBox on my Windows machine.

I have installed everything needed so far but after running git clone https://github.com/eosio/eos --recursive, I enter ls into the terminal and see eos, great then cd eos, then ls, then the screenshot shows what I'm seeing...no eosio_build.sh.

Anyone know whats going wrong? This is driving me mad!!!

Thanks all.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the scripts for building eosio in the scripts-folder.

Do

```
$ cd scripts
$ ./eosio_build.sh
```

or

```
$ ./scripts/eosio_build.sh
```

to build eosio.

**EDIT:**

follow this guide to [Build from Shell Scripts](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/install/build-from-source/shell-scripts/build-eosio-binaries)

or this guide [to install prebuild binaries](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/install/install-prebuilt-binaries)

Comment: Thanks for you help my friend. However when I enter the above I get 'command not found' so I have tried reinstalling everything and I still end up at the same point...I may just have to give up. No idea what is going wrong here.

Comment: Do you know of any good videos guides? I've tried looking but they are a few years old and I still get stuck at the same point! Thanks.

Comment: you probably need to add permission to execute with "chmod +x ./scripts/eosio_build.sh"